# How to get an approximation of a function given a chart?

Tags: distributions, data-visualization

We are developing a cache for virtual reality images for painting recognition. To simulate our approach and make tests, we submit queries according to the visit distribution of a museum.

Unfortunately, there is not a lot of documentation about this, except [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.00108) work, where Figure 3 is the "distribution of the stay time by visiting hour". I don't know if I can copy here a screenshot, let me know about it.

Another useful source is "Popular Times" by google. For example, this is the chart by searching "Uffizi Firenze":

[image]

Unfortunately, no data is available on Popular Times.

So I need to create two approximation functions for:

1. The chart in figure 3 about the visit time in the Louvre from the first paper
2. The popular times by Google that I posted above (or similar)

How can I do it?

Comment: The second is just an unnormalized histogram. You read the height of each bar, then divide by its sum.

Comment: @mugen thanks for your comment but...unfortunately there is no height.

Comment: I mean, the height of each plot isn't labelled, but you can still measure the height in pixels. Measure how many vertical pixels there is in each bin, then divide them by some baseline value to get a normalized measure. If the denominator is the height of the first bin, then it becomes a relative measure to the opening (ex. At a given time there's twice the visitors than opening time).